# What is expected when I'm asked to be ready to work by shift start?

Tags: professionalism

My employer is asking people to be ready and present for the shift-start briefing.

What is normal for an employer to expect me to have done before the shift-start briefing and what is acceptable to do after the meeting?  E.g.:

- Visiting the bathroom
- Getting a fresh coffee

Comment: Thank you these three answers, were sufficient

Answer (score 4):

In simplest terms, the 'norm' is that you are at your station at the designated start time and are ready to start work. That means that you've gotten your coffee, taken the bathroom break you needed, have your required tools, implements and whatnot and are able to start your assigned work without further delay.

This can vary widely depending upon the type of work you do and the technicalities of labor laws where you work. Not all of these variations are beneficial to the employee.

For example, if you are a waiter, it's common practice (in the US at least) to require waitstaff to be onsite and perform some side work/preparation prior to the start of your shift. Although this is part of your job responsibilities, in most cases waitstaff aren't allowed to actually clock in before the actual start of the shift.

But your question reads to me as if your boss is simply asking that you show up to the briefing on time and ready to start the meeting. A rather common sense thing to be honest.

Comment: +1 for your last line. That common sense is typically lost on people in my workplace it seems.  8am start time means you are ready to work at your desk at 8am; not you've graciously arrived at 8am and now would like to spend the next 30 minutes getting breakfast/coffee.

Comment: When I worked as a welder (no, I really did -- honest), we had to clock in before we could check out tools and material. But once we clocked in, we weren't supposed to pee or get coffee or screw around. It was clock in, go to your locker, get your materials, go weld something.

Comment: @JulieinAustin I've seen this variation as well. The 'norm' can vary widely.

Comment: @Busse It really depends of the company's culture. Where I work, everyone arrive at 8 am and we all (including the boss) take breakfast together and discuss together. And thanks to that flexibiiy, employees don't mind staying late if needed be. In my previous company, it was like you said, 8am = behind the screen and ready to work, and honestly, I hated it.

Comment: @TomW., Well I'll be. That sounds fantastic. I can definitely see how it can improve employee engagement, especially with the boss being involved. Despite that, I've worked with so many different types of people over the years, I can still recall people I know who would have hated that type of morning.

Answer (score 2):

> what is norm for showing up before shift start, to ensure they can
>   start on time?

A good rule of thumb would be to allow your self 15 minutes to get your preparations made prior to the briefing.  YMMV

Answer (score 2):

> what is norm for showing up before shift start, to ensure they can start on time?

That depends on a lot of factors:

- Do you normally get coffee/tea before shifts?
- Do you have chats at the watercooler?
- Do you need certain gear from a locker?
- Do you need to put on protective clothing according to your HSSE regulation?
- Do you have long ways through the building getting across from one side to the briefing-room?
- Your ATOTT (average time on the toilet) - in the case you haven't had a visit @home already..

The best approach would be to take the average amount spent each day on such activities before the briefing, add 5 minutes to that figure in case you have a red wave (traffic-lights) or delays of puplic transportation on your way to work and make sure you show up early according to that calculation.